# What are the potential problems of having files with one or more spaces at the beginning of the file name?

Tags: windows, filesystems, filenames

In Windows 7 and later, what problems could be caused by having one or more spaces at the beginning of the file name?

It seems like a bad idea, but does it actually cause problems?  If so, what problems?

Note that Windows Explorer won't let the user create them in Windows Vista and later, but other programs can create them.

Comment: Can someone who downvoted or placed this question on hold explain why it is opinion-based, and how to modify this question to not be?  I'm seeking factual downsides (errors, etc.), not opinions.

Comment: I modified the title and first line to draw less opinion-type answers. Your question is now close enough to draw some factual conclusions, in my opinion. I think the problem was the phrase "potential downsides". Potentials and downsides are usually based on opinion. "Typical problems" are more factual.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *ren* at the command line to create such file names.

1. You can't simply delete the spaces since Windows Explorer complains that the source and destination file names are the same. You can go through a multi-step rename process or simply use the *ren* command.
2. Some programs may not be able to open or save such files and consequently complain.

More problems might probably crop up with various apps but it's obviously not possible to list them all here.